# Toggle Network Filters

Tags: terminal, network, command-line, vpn, proxy

**What terminal commands list/toggle `Status` for network `Filters & Proxies`?**

---

**Background**: Cisco Secure Client (VPN) has added three network filters:

[image: cisco network filters for vpn]

Disconnecting and closing Cisco Secure Client does not disable these filters. When Cisco Secure Client opens the filters (if disabled) are automatically enabled.

**Why this is a problem:**

The expected behavior would be for them to become disabled automatically when the Cisco Secure Client is closed.

---

**What I've tried**:

I manually toggle each of the three filters' `Status` to `Disabled`. Manually disabling the filters is time consuming.

I have been searching for terminal commands to interact with (disable) MacOS Network Filters. Though it does not list the filters, the only terminal command I have been able to find is this one:

```
sudo networksetup -listallnetworkservices
```

Obviously this does *not* list the *filters*. It lists services (eg. `Thunderbolt Bridge`, `Wi-Fi`).

I have also reviewed the following related stackexchanges:

- [What Are Socket Filters and What Do They Do?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/438941/what-are-socket-filters-and-what-do-they-do)
- [How to cancel authorization to filter network content in Macbook?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/452212/how-to-cancel-authorization-to-filter-network-content-in-macbook)

These do not provide cli commands for toggling network filters.

---

**Note**: Since the MacOS System Settings can Enable and Disable the Status of the filters, it seems probably that there is a command that can also toggle the filters.

[image: system settings allows enable/disable]

---

**Update** @Thinkr pointed me to the plist, here is a gif of how it changes (left is system settings where i am enabling/disabling and right is xcode which is watching the plist changes); the plist file for those is located here: `/Library/Preferences/com.apple.networkextension.plist`.

[image]

Comment: A filter is *not* a network service so you won’t be able to control it like that. Your network traffic will be routed to a virtual adapter which should be listed in `networksetup` (somewhere) but those filters will be entirely software controlled.

Comment: Does the System Settings panel allow for the Status to be toggled from Enabled to Disabled? I'm under the persuasion that if the mac os gui can control the filter, that there is a cli call that can also control the filter.

Comment: For your info, the plist file for those is located here: `/Library/Preferences/com.apple.networkextension.plist`.

Comment: @Thinkr interesting, thanks. i opened it with xcode; it's got cisco in it multiple times. i don't see a way to enable/disable though. is there a path whereby i have two plist files and copy the desired one into place and do some kind of plist refresh?

Comment: Maybe something like deleting it (but saving a copy) and put it back again after. (Don't try this since I wasn't able to test it  and I don't want you to lose your setup)

Comment: The problem with plist files is that every time you modify it, you must reload the service which entails killing it first, then starting it again.  In this case, you’ll need to kill networking then start it and I don’t imagine you wanting to bring down your *network* every time you toggle a switch.

Comment: @Allan What I said in the previous comment...

Comment: @Allan actually, when i'm changing the vpn i am changing my network...so i think that's okay.  are you suggesting that `(a) cp enabled plist; restart networking and (b) cp disabled plist; restart networking;` could be a solution?

Comment: I think you’re missing the point.  When you restart the network service, you don’t just take down IPs, you disable *all* network interfaces, services, etc.  Toggling a filter/proxy is like opening/closing a gate to a roadside checkpoint.

Comment: Hmm, is the point that restarting _all_ the network interfaces is time consuming? I'm imagining that it happens in a matter of hundreds of milliseconds. Is that misguided? Anyway, i'm not sure i have a path to a solution here even if it is a half a second to restart. It's unclear at this point if my `a` `b` is feasible or not.